# Different methods to get SHA1 give different results

Tags: git, hashsum

I'm learning about SHA1 (specifically wrt Git), and I wanted to sanity-check my understanding by calculating a string's SHA1 with different methods - I expected identical SHA1 hashes, but instead I got distinct results from three of four methods:

```
>git hash-object --stdin <<< "Apple Pie"
23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5
```

.

```
>sha1sum <<< "blob 9\0Apple Pie"
332cd56150dc8b954c0b859bd4aa6092beafa00f  -
```

.

```
>printf 'blob 9\0Apple Pie' > foo.txt
>sha1sum foo.txt
9eed377bbdeb4aa5d14f8df9cd50fed042f41023  foo.txt
```

.

```
>openssl sha1 foo.txt
SHA1(foo.txt)= 9eed377bbdeb4aa5d14f8df9cd50fed042f41023
```

The accepted answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290444/why-does-git-hash-object-return-a-different-hash-than-openssl-sha1) says that `git hash-object` runs a SHA1 hash on the specified content prefixed with "blob [file size]/0". Thus I explicitly prefixed that text to the strings I tested with the non-git method.

Why all these different results? I thought SHA1 was a specific and unique hash of a given string, and that there were not different "types" of SHA1 - is that not true?

Comment: Use `hexdump -C` instead of `sha1sum` and you'll see the there's already a difference in your input.

Comment: ...and `printf 'blob 10\0Apple Pie\n' | sha1sum` happens to be what `git` reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences don't come from SHA1, but the input. The here-string syntax appends a newline, as we can see with `od`:

```
$ od -c <<< foo
0000000   f   o   o  \n
```

So in your `git` command the input is the ten characters `Apple Pie\n`.

In addition, the double quotes you used in the here-strings don't support backslash escapes like `\n` or `\nnn`, so `<<< "blob 9\0Apple Pie"` gives a string containing a literal backslash and a zero.

`printf` however does interpret `\0` as the NUL byte, and it doesn't add a trailing newline, so with the newline added and the length fixed, we should get the expected output:

```
$ printf 'blob 10\0Apple Pie\n' | sha1sum
23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5  -
```

We could try to do the same with the here-string using the `$''` quote which does support `\0` as representing the NUL byte, but that may not work in all shells, since the NUL byte ends the string. E.g. Bash cannot deal with it, `zsh` can:

```
$ zsh -c "sha1sum <<< $'blob 10\0Apple Pie'"
23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5  -
```

Comment: String-handling in Bash continues to flummox me. Thank you for both answering the question and shedding a little bit more light on Bash string-handling.